# Как внести изменения в базу данных postgreSQL на сервере Ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, postgresql

Залил на хостинг интернет-магазин и со временем вылезла ошибка следующего характера. В базе данных есть классы Пользователь, Товар и Корзина. И если пользователь заносит товар в корзину, а админ удаляет данный товар из перечня доступных(просто удаляет его), то вылезает ошибка несостыковки. Понятно, что это связанно с тем, что я не прописал CASCADE удаления той корзины, товара которой не существует. Но теперь как мне с сервера удалить в ручную эти корзины? Просто удалить эти корзины не получается, вылезает ошибка. Смог смоделировать такое проблему на локалке и решить ее посредством удаления таких корзин в ручную командой Cart.objects.filter(id="корзина, товара которой уже не существует").delete() это все делал через shell, но как мне это осуществить на сервере, на котором Ubuntu с базой данных postgreSQL?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Просто удалить эти корзины не получается, вылезает ошибка` - добавьте в вопрос, как вы пробуете это делать (каким запросом) и что за ошибка появляется

Comment: `как мне это осуществить на сервере` — так же, как и «не на сервере».

Comment: Не на сервере, я решаю эту проблему ручным удалением не нужной корзины, через команду shell, затем я прописываю Cart.objects.filter(id="не нужная корзина").delete(), а на сервере так не выходит

Comment: На сервере я пробую удалить эти корзины через администратора django, а ошибка вылезает 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title', я думаю это ошибка вылезает потому что он не понимает, что нужно удалять, так как этого товара уже не существует. Как мне через базу данных PosgreSQL произвести удаление?

Comment: @ЕгорКопица подключитесь к БД через менеджер и руками поправте таблицы. Если нет менеджера/нет возможности, то на сервере через psql подключитесь к БД и обычным sql уже наводите порядок)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, когда залез вручную в базу данных и в лоб удалил "неправильные" корзины.